# Change idle screen

Tags: screen, lock-screens

Is there some way to change the "sweep glass" idle screen (screen you see when the phone comes back from turning off screen)?

I like the "sweep glass" screen, but have seen some others. Eg. Screen similar to the "phone call" screen - two options (answer, reject) that need to be swiped to either side.

Aside: idea of puzzle pieces for messages, emails, etc is brilliant!

Answer (score 2):

I've been using [WidgetLocker](http://teslacoilsw.com/) ([AppBrain](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.teslacoilsw.widgetlocker)). Its very customizable and has worked like a charm for me.

[image: WidgetLocker QR Code]

Comment: Note: WidgetLocker is not free.

Comment: Not willing to pay for apps just yet. Gotta figure out the stuff I have first. Plus there's so many free apps...

Comment: @cofiem Skip a coffee break at Starbucks and buy yourself a couple of apps.  Developers need the support so they can make more awesome apps for everyone.  Plus, there is a 24 hour return period so you can get your money back if you do not like the app (unlike Apple where all purchases are final).

Comment: @Bryan Denny This article sums up my feelings pretty well. I haven't yet explored everything on the phone, and don't yet feel like I want to go buy things. http://fury.com/2010/09/the-first-step-to-fixing-the-android-marketplace-has-nothing-to-do-with-the-android-marketplace/

Answer (score 1):

There's [flyscreen](http://www.myflyscreen.com/), which lets you put widgets and such on your lock screen. ([App brain link](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.flydroid.FlyScreen))

Comment: I'll give it a go.